# Can't replace new line from file

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have a file like

```
string:number:number
string:number:number
stringForReplace:number:number
string:number:number
string:number:number
```

I need to remove string with stringForReplace.
This is what I do in php.

```
    $fileContent=file_get_contents("...");
    $fileContent=preg_replace("/stringForReplace\:".$number1."\:".$number2."/", "", $fileContent);
    $file=fopen("...","w");
    fwrite($file, $fileContent);
    fclose($file);
```

This removes string but empty line remains. I used \s \n in the end of expression. also such things as [\s\n]+ also tried to trim and str_replace of '\n'. But nothig works. What's proper solution?

Comment: Adding a `\n` at the end of the pattern (`$number2 . "\n/",`) works for me.

Comment: Strange but result remains.

Comment: Don't understand what minus for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

changing the closing "/" to "[\s\r]*\n/" should have done it.  Here's my test:

```
% php -r '$x = "x\ny\nx\ny\n"; echo $x; echo preg_replace("/x\n/", "", $x);'
x
y
x
y
y
y
```